# Words for a writer to stop writing

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for or a common expression that describes when a writer has decided to stop writing? Think of a poet or a book writer who has decided to stop writing.

> The author has decided to retired from writing.
>
> The author has decided to stop writing again.
>
> The author has decided to stop writing until she finds reasons.
>
> The author has decided to seal her pen.”

These are the ways I can think of, but I wonder if there specific words/expression. In Chinese, I’d just write 封筆, in which the first word means “seal”, and the second word means “pen/pencil/calligraphy brush” (you get the point).

Comment: Something like _he threw in the towel_? Is he tired or lacking determination? OR is he stopping because he's at his peak?

Comment: Not really (but thanks). I checked it, it means quit in defeat.

Comment: Okay why the downvote? Seriously?

Comment: Not my downvote. But, you haven't answered my question fully yet.

Comment: An author never *decides* to stop writing.  They either run intro "writer's block" or they get caught in a cycle of doing everything but actually writing, possibly because they're afraid they forgotten how.

Comment: I am not sure if I get the second part, please elaborate. But if you are suggesting a writer/author would not have stopped writing for other (but positive) personal reasons, I am not sure if I can agree with that at all.

Comment: Footballers "hang up their boots".

Comment: @HotLicks a writer might decide to stop writing professionally, just as I decided to stop writing such computer code. Was that your own experience?

Comment: Are you looking for a way of saying 'stopping' but very specific to writing? You first three examples could apply to any activity. Also, I don't get the point about 'seal' and 'pen' or 'brush' - those don't go together at all. 'Seal' as in the animal? 'Seal' as in close an envelope with by licking the adhesive?

Comment: @WeatherVane - If you decide to stop you're not much of a writer.

Comment: @CppLearner - I feel like you're asking because you're writing a biography about a retired writer? Or maybe you're asking because you're creating a fictional story concerning a writer? I feel like the reason the writer has stopped writing is not relevant to the question.

Comment: We used to say 'lay down'. Now we say 'set down'. 'Hang up' hasn't really gained traction yet. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hang+up+his+pen%2Cset+down+his+pen%2C+lay+down+his+pen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chang%20up%20his%20pen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cset%20down%20his%20pen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clay%20down%20his%20pen%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 9):

Try this expression.

"The author **set down her pen**."

You can definitely choose to add the words *has decided to* if you would like. Alternatively, you could substitute *author* with *writer*. This is entirely up to you, though.

Also, consider using the word *hiatus*. I don't have enough context, so I can't give any advice on how to use this word, but you might be able to work something out.

Comment: Great find. _Set down (one's) pen_ has examples on Google. I recommend quoting a few examples from major sites.

Comment: Actually, **laid down her pen** seems to be more common.

Answer (score 4):

Rappers hang up their mic, superheroes, their cape, football players, their boots, and so on. Other examples include: fiddle, sword, gloves, etc.

Thus the construction *hang up one's (item)* is pretty easily understood.

By extension, a writer **hangs up his pen**. It might sound funny, because pens aren't usually hung.

Since dictionaries don't list each and every variation of a phrase, you'll have to depend on usage examples seen online.

An example from [*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2002/jan/31/stephenking.fiction).

> Stephen King, the sultan of shock and one of the world's most successful, imitated and prolific authors, may finally be **hanging up his pen, closing his laptop or doing whatever writers do when they decide they have nothing left they want to say.** He has no desire, he says, to keep on writing for the sake of writing.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

An example from [*The New York Times*](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2000/08/23/books/when-it-time-hang-up-pen-it-s-my-last-book-really-no-mean-really-really.html).

> When Is It Time To Hang Up the Pen?; 'It's My Last Book. Really. No, I Mean Really, Really.'